# Presentation of non-printable characters in messages

Tags: register

Vim has two options to represent non-printable characters - as a single char or using key-notation: `^J` or `<C-J>`.

By default, vim uses a single-char representation for `:reg` command:
`"q       kkj^D^D^y^y`

Is there an option to change this representation to using key-notation (in vim or neovim)?
`"q       kkj<C-D><C-D><C-Y><C-Y>`

[image]

Comment: The short version is that you can't do that without modifying the source code.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!